# socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python-3.x

Boa tarde!

Estou estudando Python e me deparei com um problema ao estudar sobre network (biblioteca socket). Eu tenho o seguinte pedaço de código

```
import socket
mysock =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

mysock.connect(('http://data.pr4e.org/', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True :
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1) :
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

Pelo que verifiquei todos os linkes funcionam e estão sem problemas, porém ao executar o script um erro é mostrado na tela

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\PythonMichiganSchool\network\script.py", line 4, in <module>
    mysock.connect(('http://data.pr4e.org/', 80))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Eu tentei trocar os links e testar eles, reescrevi o código e li a documentação da biblioteca e até algumas respostas aqui no stackoverflow, porém não obtive sucesso na resolução do problema

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver este problema, você deve retirar o HTTP:// da seguinte linha

```
mysock.connect(('http://data.pr4e.org/', 80))
```

Após isto troque o código '\n\n' para '\r\n\r\n
O código ficará como o código abaixo :

```
import socket
mysock =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True :
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data) < 1) :
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```